# Datatables - scroll issue only in IE9

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have an issue with Datatables not using its x-axis scroll correctly.

I was previously faced with the IE9 'ghost cell' issue, which I was able to fix. However, now I'm running into a problem where my overflow-x is shown, instead of hiding it and making the window scrollable.

My Datatables initialization:

```
 var oTable = $('#tableBP').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "sScrollXInner": "200%",
        "sScrollY": 300,
        "bScrollCollapse": false,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bSort": false,
        "bInfo": false,
        "bPaginate": false
    });

    //This is a Datatables plugin. The issue occurs whether I comment this part or not.
    new FixedColumns(oTable, { 
        "iLeftWidth": 225
    });
```

This is what I'm faced with: [image: overflowX not working like it should]

It works in IE9 compatibility mode though. Unfortunately, other parts of the page do not allow me te run this is a lower version compatibility, but this clearly marks it as a IE9 only issue. No issues in Chrome, Safari, Opera, Firefox.

I'm not going to post the table here because of its sheer size (2000+ td fields in some cases). It is a perfectly valid HTML table with a thead/tbody, and all whitespaces between the tags have been removed (this is what fixed my previous ghost cell issue).

Anyone have any experience with Datatables and know the root cause of this issue?

PS: this is an MVC2 app (C#.Net) but this issue seems unrelated to the application that generated this webpage.

**Update**

I forgot to mention the following part:

The table used to be displayed properly; but due to IE9's ghost cell issue in large tables, I was forced to clean all whitespaces from between my table/thead/tbody/tr/td tags.
I resolved this by forcing a regex replace on my aplication's HTML output:

```
// response is the string with my HTML output which will be written to the browser after this:

string expression = @">[ \t\r\n\v\f]*<td"; 
response = Regex.Replace(response, expression, @"> <td");
```

If I comment out the RegEx replace, the overflow of datatables works perfectly, but I'm faced with the ghost cell issue which cause misalignment and all-round ugliness.
When uncommented, all cells are perfectly aligned, but the overflow stops working.

Like I said, the issue only pertains to IE9. All other browsers(including IE9 in compatibility mode) render the table perfectly in both commented/uncommented states.

Comment: can you post a link to a working example? (perhaps even the site itself?)

Comment: Hosting this publically is unfortunately impossible due to privacy restrictions. I can paste the HTML of a smaller version of the table if you like (the pure table HTML after Datatables has been applied is up at http://pastehtml.com/view/cbxlna71j.html). Getting the 'before' HTML is a bit harder, working on that now.

Comment: Thanks, but it is essential to have the complete set (html+css). I think the problem is most likely in the CSS, as it seems the table is flowing out of its container (if I judge the screenshot correctly)

Comment: It's not a CSS issue. I have changed the HTML output of the application slightly, the issue was nog happening before. I will update my question, give me 5 mins :-)

Comment: Well, judging the source on pastehtml, I can clearly see inline css styling (width:100%; on the table scrollHead, and width: 1558px; on dataTables_scroll) :-)

Comment: Correct. the 1558px is Datatables' work, not mine. I only enforce the upper 100% width; the rest is up to Datatables. I've been noticing that the plugin doesn't like me trying to enfore styles :) Also, I've updated my question with info that proves (I think) this isn't just a CSS issue. (If it is a CSS issue, Datatables is misapplying it, and I'll need to override the plugin file, which seems a last resort call to me).

Comment: Ok, then I can't really help. last tip: have you tried adding 'overflow-x:scroll;' to the wrapper div?

Comment: Yep, was the first thing I tried. I was convinced it worked well, until I noticed you have to scroll to the right before you can see the vertical scroll bar. Which isn't really good design if I'd leave it like that.

Comment: That's really weird. Can't you do a poor-man's HTML by doing a 'save page' in your browser, then uploading it somewhere?

Comment: I've uploaded a zipfile to http://staging.fusebox.be/StackOverflow_PageSave.zip It contains a saved servsion of the page and a folder with all JS/CSS files included. Funny things is, once I saved the page and opened it in Chrome, the issue was also occuring there. So I suspect Datatables of setting some wrong CSS/HTML, which I in turn saved, and which now causes this to be erroneous in all browser. It seems to point to Datatables doing something wrong with the table transformation when the browser is Internet Explorer 9...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to fix the issue, after a lot of searching and patience.

The issue was Bootstrap related. Well, not Bootstrap exactly, but what Bootstrap.css does is add a `max-width: 100%;` to every table. Which is great for general layout, but apparently IE9 can't combine that with a scrollable `overflow-x` setup. IE9 doesn't really like max- and min- heights and widths from my experience.

But I still want to thank all of you for your efforts, you put me on the right road to find the root cause of this issue!

Comment: Ah, that explains a lot! (and a shame I missed that :-)) Good luck with your project / succes nog met je project!

Comment: @Flater, you can play with 'box-sizing' property.

Comment: I probably could, but it needed to be consistent in all browsers. Also, I feel that Bootstrap is quite dominant in its CSS, and I didn't want to start messing with it too much because it might screw up other parts of the website.

Answer (score 2):

Add this, in `demo_table_jui.css` at line 117 (below `.dataTables_wrapper`):

```
.DTFC_ScrollWrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

This does the trick (at least, over here it does, in all browsers including both IE7 & IE8 document mode in IE9).

[image: working horizontalscroll (no vertical scrollbar), header with searchbox stays in view]

**Edited**: the overflow code should not be added to `.dataTables_wrapper` as I suggested earlier in this answer, but the class `.DTFC ScrollWrapper` should be specified with overflowing instead, see above code.

---

btw, totally irrelevant: this company always reminds me of 'De Bende van Nijvel', don't ask me why ;)

Comment: I like the solution, but there's still two problems occurring: the vertical scrollbar can only be accessed if you scroll to the right. I know it's not on the example doc, but all other instances of this page contain thousend upon thousands of cells, I did't want to overburden people. Second issue is that the left column isn't fixed anymore, which it should be. But thanks for the input though, I appreciate the help!

Comment: Well then the problem is down to all the inline styles, which are dictating 'hard' widths and percentage widths. I'll look into it some more, but I can't promise there is a 'magic' sollution. The vertical scrollbars can be brought back by adding 'overflow-y: auto;' to my above code

Comment: Yeah, I suspect this is an issue in the Datatables plugin. I have seen this issue occuring for some other scenarios as wel, so it seems that there is a certain set of rules that needs to be followed if you want the overflow-x to work correctly. However, this table here is valid accoridng to all the causes that I know of. So there's probably another reason (DataTables related) why the plugin renders it incorrectly. But to me, any fix will do, whether it's a quick workaround, or a HTML structure change.

Comment: Somehow I think the code got messed up somewhere: the 'DTFC_RightWrapper' seems (judging by the name) the wrapper that would allow scrolling of the data (not the legend) of the table, yet it is completely empty, and the table content is outside this div..

Comment: DTFC = DataTables Fixed Columns (extra DataTables plugin). This plugin allows me to fix column to the left and/or right of the table. So the table content should be {Left fixed part} {scrollable contents} {right fixed part}. But I have no right fixed column, that explains why it's empty :-)

Comment: I'm affraid I can't fix it any better than my answer above (I have tried numerous tricks). This is mainly due to the layout/html generated by the DataTables plugin; it is quite a mess :-). Example: when setting a fixed with on 'dataTables_scroll', to enforce scrolling, the datatable inside it stretches to this width, so scrolling can never be forced. I think you would be best off just starting from a fresh DataTable template :(

Comment: I'm not starting off a specific template. DataTables just does this whenever I load the page (my applications renders a normal  table). But I understand your frustration, I've been looking at it for weeks and I'm still lost. Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: Yes it is a very frustrating one :) Good luck with it. Just one more thing: are you sure you implemented DTFC correctly? I see a lot of DTFC_ classes, but no corresponding css anywhere..

Comment: DTFC usage is equal to that of the example documentation. And the issue occurs whether I use DTFC or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution on `line 110` in `.dataTables_wrapper` add `overflow:auto;` after `clear:both;`

```
.dataTables_wrapper {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 302px;
    _height: 302px;
    clear: both;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**Before**

[image: Before]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/mjpmxycy.phe.png))</sub>

**After**

[image: After]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/nqhwq2t4.ihg.png))</sub>

Might want to throw an extra div around the 3 tables, and give that `overflow:auto;`, `clear:both;` if you want to sit nicely below your search toolbar.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't make the 3 tables, Datatables does. I just have a normal table, call the plugin, and it transforms it into the monster of HTML you see before you :-)

Comment: Also I tested your solution, the problem is that if you throw a scroll on the wrapper, the entire table scrolls. One of the key features of using Datatables is so my headers are fixed while scrolling. Also, this created a double vertical scrollbar. Thanks for the effort thougn, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
 * The position is changed from relative to inherit, to fix the issue with the scrolling of the wrapper.
 */

.dataTables_wrapper {
    position: inherit;
    clear: both;
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

The problem could be because of the position of the of the DIV. I have fixed the similar issue by overriding the position in the datatable css.

Comment: I tried that one. It seems to be a solution, but IE9 didn't think so. The answer I provided is the only way I managed to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by applying the following CSS:

```
/* this is needed for IE and Firefox if using horizontal scroll*/
table{
    max-width: none;
    min-height: 0%;
}
```